# React state not updating when looping through array

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a list of nested checkboxes on a redux form which are organised by region (England, Wales, Scotland) and then underneath are organisations that reside in the relevant region.

I have written a function in my component that triggers whenever a checkbox is checked which updates my selected checkboxes state, and adds the new ID. Similarly, the ID is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.

However, the other thing that a user can do is check the top level region which opens up the list and automatically checks all boxes underneath, making it easier to select all, rather than doing it individually. However, these auto-checked checkbox IDs do not get pushed into the state so when someone decides to uncheck one within the region they ALL uncheck and only the clicked one rechecks - I did some debugging and found that the state isn't including these checkboxes.

Here's the code I wrote to loop through the IDs within the region and try and add them to the state:

```
const organisationIdsToAdd = regionalOrganisationIds.filter(organisationId => {
    return !this.state.regionOrganisationsMapping[toggledRegionId].includes(organisationId);
});

let updatedOrganisationIds = [];

organisationIdsToAdd.map(oid => {
    if(!this.state.updatedOrganisationIds.includes(oid)) {
        updatedOrganisationIds = [...this.state.updatedOrganisationIds, oid];
    } else {
        updatedOrganisationIds = this.state.updatedOrganisationIds.filter(orgId => orgId !== oid);
    }
});
```

This code happens in a function called `_toggleRegionSelection()` which runs whenever a region checkbox is clicked. The region ID is passed as a parameter. Once this is done I set the state:

```
this.setState({ updatedOrganisationIds });
```

Then run this:

```
this.props.onOrganisationChange(organisationIdsToAdd);
```

To send the call back to the form and update the values of the checkboxes. However, the state always comes back blank (provided the user clicks the region on page load). The region itself does NOT need to be in the state however, just the organisations.

I tried using `this.state.updatedOrganisationIds.push()` but was told that states are immutible and should not be updated this way - but how can I do what I need to if the way I've done it doesn't work?

Comment: Firstly, if you are managing the state in a component then it is not immutable. You can mutate the state any way you want. 

But if you are storing the props in your state then it should not be mutated as **props** are immutable.

I don't know what is the way you are doing this but if you are doing this by maintaining the state in the component then you can use `this.state.updatedOrganisationIds.push()`.

Comment: You mentioned that redux is used in your app, so is there any reason to have a state, while you can move everything to redux? To me, having 2 sources of truth is a chore to maintain data consistency between state and redux's store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. Firstly in your loop you reassign updatedOrganisationIds whenever the previous updatedOrganisationIds contains the oid which basically throws away all of the ones you've added so far. Secondly you shouldn't use the state like that when you are updating state based on the current state. Thirdly I'm not sure why you are using map when you don't then use the array it returns, use forEach if you don't intend on using the array afterwards.

You could try something like this: (notice how I use the previous state)

```
const organisationIdsToAdd = regionalOrganisationIds.filter(organisationId => {
  return !this.state.regionOrganisationsMapping[toggledRegionId].includes(organisationId);
});

this.setState((prevState) => {
  let updatedOrganisationIds = Object.assign([], prevState.updatedOrganisationIds);
  organisationIdsToAdd.forEach((oid) => {
    const index = updatedOrganisationIds.indexOf(oid);
    if (index === -1) {
      updatedOrganisationIds.push(oid);
    } else {
      updatedOrganisationIds.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  return { updatedOrganisationIds };
});
```